Deriving an Estimator Using Survey Means from Individual Forecasts
I would like to clarify a doubt regarding the paper Testing the Rationality of Price Forecasts: New Evidence from Panel Data (by MICHAEL P. KEANE AND DAVID E. RUNKLE). DOI: 10.2307/2006704
The paper is about the rationality of experts' price forecasts.
In this cotext, $_tP_{i,t+k}$ is the $k$-step-ahead prediction of $P_t$ made at time $t$ by forecaster $i$, with $i=1,\ldots,N$ forecasters and $t=1,\ldots,T$.
For an individual forecaster, a test of rationality can be performed by running the regression:
$$\label{eq2}
P_{t+k}= \alpha_0 + \alpha_{1} \,\, _tP_{i,t+k} + \alpha_2 X_{i,t} + \varepsilon_{t,k}^i \tag{2}
$$
where $X_{i,t}$ is any variable in forecaster i's information set at time $t$. Unbiasedness requires that, in a regression without $X_{i,t}$ variables, the coefficients in equation (\ref{eq2})
may be restricted to $\alpha_0 = 0$ and $\alpha_1= 1$.
The Aggregation Problem
Using survey means to test the rational expectations hypothesis leads to serious specification error (bias). This bias can be illustrated by comparing the results of three separate tests of unbiasedness using equation (\ref{eq2}).

First doing a separate regression for each individual and taking the mean of the estimated coefficients:
\begin{equation}\label{eq3}
 \hat{\alpha}_{1i}:=\frac1N\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{\sum_{t=1}^T P_{t+k} \,\,\, _tP_{i,t+k} }{\sum_{t=1}^T   \, _tP_{i,t+k}^2 }.\tag{3}
\end{equation}

Second using the pooled data:
\begin{equation}\label{eq4}
 \hat{\alpha}_{1p}:=\frac{\sum_{t=1}^T \sum_{i=1}^N P_{t+k}\,\,\, _tP_{i,t+k} }{\sum_{t=1}^T  \sum_{i=1}^N  \, _tP_{i,t+k}^2 }.\tag{4}
\end{equation}

Third using survey means:
\begin{equation}\label{sm123}
\hat{\alpha}_{1m} = \frac{\sum_{t=1}^T P_{t+k}\left(\sum_{i=1}^N {}_tP_{i,t+k}\right)}{\sum_{t=1}^T\left(\sum_{i=1}^N {}_tP_{i,t+k}^2\right)}\tag{5}.
\end{equation}


I am interested in deriving $\hat{\alpha}_{1m}$,  in  the Equation (\ref{sm123}).
Before that, it is useful to derive the (\ref{eq3}) equation.

OLS
For this, let’s recall a simple linear regression model:
\begin{equation}
y_t = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 x_t + \varepsilon_t, \quad t=1,\ldots,T.
\end{equation}
In matrix form:
$$
Y = X\alpha + \varepsilon,
$$
where $X$ is a $T \times 2$ matrix with a column of ones and a column of $x_t$ values, and $\alpha = (\alpha_0,\alpha_1)$. The OLS estimator is given by:
\begin{equation}
 \hat{\alpha} = (X'X)^{-1}X'Y.
\end{equation}
Defining the sample means of $x_t$ and $y_t$:
$$
\bar{x} = \frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T x_t, \quad \bar{y} = \frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T y_t,
$$
we have the well-known OLS formulas:
\begin{equation}\label{ols123}
\hat{\alpha}_1 = \frac{\sum_{t=1}^T (x_t - \bar{x})(y_t - \bar{y})}{\sum_{t=1}^T (x_t - \bar{x})^2},
\quad
\hat{\alpha}_0 = \bar{y} - \hat{\alpha}_1 \bar{x}.\tag{I} 
\end{equation}

For an individual forecaster, a test of rationality can be performed by running the regression:
\begin{equation}\label{II}
 P_{t+k}=\alpha_{0}+\alpha_{1}\,\, _tP_{i,t+k}+\varepsilon_{t,k}^{i}\tag{II}
\end{equation}
If we assume:
$$
\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T P_{t+k} = 0 \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T \, _tP_{i,t+k} = 0,
$$
we can use the formula (\ref{ols123}) to conclude that:
$$
\hat{\alpha}_1 = \frac{\sum_{t=1}^T \, _tP_{i,t+k} \,\,P_{t+k}}{\sum_{t=1}^T   \, _tP_{i,t+k}^2}.
$$
Taking the mean, we have (\ref{eq3})

We turn to deriving the estimator $\hat{\alpha}_{1m}$.
My Attempt
The authors do not explicitly define the survey means. I will assume  that the survey mean forecast at time $t$ is denoted as:
$$
_t\overline{P}_{t+k} \equiv \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N\, _tP_{i,t+k}.
$$
Replacing $_tP_{i,t+k}$ in (\ref{II}) with the survey mean forecast $_t\overline{P}_{t+k}$, we have:
$$
P_{t+k} = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 \, _t\overline{P}_{t+k} + u_{t+k},
$$
So one might expect an analogous derivation. Assuming $\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T \, _t\overline{P}_{t+k}=0$, and apply OLS in a standard way, I would write:
\begin{equation}\label{estimator045}
\hat{\alpha}_1 = \frac{\sum_{t=1}^T \, _t\overline{P}_{t+k} P_{t+k} }{\sum_{t=1}^T (_t\overline{P}_{t+k})^2}.\tag{III}
\end{equation}
Now, let’s attempt to expand $_t\overline{P}_{t+k}$. Since
$$
_t\overline{P}_{t+k} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N {}_tP_{i,t+k},
$$
For the numerator, we have
$$
\sum_{t=1}^T (_t\overline{P}_{t+k} P_{t+k}) = \sum_{t=1}^T \left(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N {}_tP_{i,t+k}\right)P_{t+k} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{t=1}^T P_{t+k}\left(\sum_{i=1}^N {}_tP_{i,t+k}\right).
$$
For the denominator:
$$
\sum_{t=1}^T (_t\overline{P}_{t+k})^2 = \sum_{t=1}^T \left(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N {}_tP_{i,t+k}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{t=1}^T \left(\sum_{i=1}^N {}_tP_{i,t+k}\right)^2.
$$
So the estimator (\ref{estimator045}) can be rewritten as:
$$
\hat{\alpha}_1 = \frac{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{t=1}^T P_{t+k}\left(\sum_{i=1}^N {}_tP_{i,t+k}\right) }{ \frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{t=1}^T \left(\sum_{i=1}^N {}_tP_{i,t+k}\right)^2 } = N\frac{\sum_{t=1}^T P_{t+k}\left(\sum_{i=1}^N {}_tP_{i,t+k}\right) }{ \sum_{t=1}^T \left(\sum_{i=1}^N {}_tP_{i,t+k}\right)^2 } .
$$
And this seems to be very different to $\hat{\alpha}_{1m}$ given by equation (\ref{sm123}).
How can we proceed to arrive at the exact formula for $\hat{\alpha}_{1m}$?
Thank you in advance for any help or insight.

Negative scores are very welcome as long as they help to improve the question. I would really appreciate it, if it's not too much work, tell me where to improve.

One thing that might get your more responses is that the publicly available version is here. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4980466_Testing_the_Rationality_of_Price_Forecasts_New_Evidence_from_Panel_Data

It's not accepting answers but maybe a comment will be enough because I read enough that I can answer your question. When they are doing in the survey means case, is aggregating across $i$ for a given value of $t$ and $k$ so basically forgetting about individual effects. The best way to think about it is to picture equation (2) at the top of pg 719 with $\epsilon_{t,k}$ replacing $\epsilon^{i}_{t,k}$ so that all forecasters are identical at time $t$ and horizon $k$, The survey means case assumes that one can just average over  $i$ for that given $t$ and $k$ and use the average observation.

Obviously, this is not a good thing to do and they show later that it produces upward biased estimates of the coefficients. My guess is that the question got closed because it is more relevant for crossvalidated.se or economics.se.

I already asked on crossvalidated.se, but I didn't get an answer. That's why I decided to post it here. Honestly, I didn't think I would be rejected here. Yes, I have the article, but my question is not understanding the bias, but rather obtaining the estimator from a simple OLS regression.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/658440/difficulty-in-deriving-an-estimator-using-survey-means-from-individual-forecasts
